# Problem with Patrol while running integration test in Flutter

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol

I have problem with Patrol while running integration test in Flutter. I need to accept some permissions and I want to use to this purpose Petrol package.But in terminal there is an error which seems like this:

```
Patrol (native): configure() started
Patrol (native): configure() failed
Patrol (native): configure() failed: (GrpcError: configure() failed with code UNAVAILABLE (Error connecting: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 53108))
Patrol (native): trying to configure() again in 1 second
```

Here is my code, in which I initialize NativeAutomator.

```
void main() async {
  final IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();

  binding.framePolicy = LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBindingFramePolicy.fullyLive;

  final automator = NativeAutomator(
    config: NativeAutomatorConfig(
            packageName: 'my.app.android.id',
            bundleId: 'my.app.ios.id',
        ),
  );

  await automator.configure();

  testWidgets('Log Out', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await SharedPreferencesHelper.clear();

    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 15));

    await TestHelper.delayUntil(
      tester,
      find.byType(LoginBody),
    );

    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    await tester.enterText(
      Consts.email,
    );
    await delayUI();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.enterText(
      Consts.password,
    );
    await delayUI();
    await tester.tap(find.byType(Button));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));

    automator.grantPermissionOnlyThisTime();

    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    
    expect(find.byType(LoginBody), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Not Use patrol in widget test You have to use **patrolTest** and **patrol_cli**
and command would be :

```
patrol test integration_test/example_test.dart
```

eg:

```
patrolTest(
'selects an image using a native file picker',
nativeAutomation: true,
($) async {
  await $.pumpWidgetAndSettle(
    MainApp(
      key: UniqueKey(),
    ),
  );

  await $('Open file picker').tap();

  expect(find.byKey(const Key('image_0')), findsNothing);

  await $.native.tap(Selector(text: 'download.jpg'));
  await $.pumpAndSettle();
  await $.pumpAndSettle();

  expect(find.byKey(const Key('image_0')), findsOneWidget);
},
 );
```

Comment: According to the documentation you can use patrol in widget test.
https://patrol.leancode.co/native/advanced

Comment: Try to run with patrol_cli command. and according to me u can't use integration test binding while u using patrol.